# jQuery ".on('click')" event works only once. Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slider

I've been looking for a solution that I couldn't find.

I built a simple image slider where every time you click on the picture this should change with the follow one. Specifically, on-click event move the css property z-index to the next picture using addClass and removeClass.

The problem is that it works only the first time you press on and never again, this means I can show only the first and the second picture. I cannot find solution, what I'm looking for is just how to get the on-click event work every time I click on the picture?

```js
var currentImg = $(".active");
var nextImg = currentImg.next();

$(".imageSlider").on("click", function() {
 alert("ciao");
 currentImg.removeClass(".active").css("z-index", 0);
 nextImg.addClass(".active").css("z-index", 10);
});
```

```css
.active  {z-index: 10;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="imageSlider">
 <div class="images">
  <img src="JLT1.jpg" class="active" height="500px" width="700px">
  <img src="JLT2.jpg" height="500px" width="700px">
  <img src="JLT3.jpg" height="500px" width="700px">
  <img src="JLT4.jpg" height="500px" width="700px">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: every time click event is fired you should update currentImg e nextImg, use $('.active',this) inside onclick function

Comment: Don't use **dot** for `addClass` or `removeClass`. After all, it's bad idea to show next image with playing `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

1. `currentImg = $(".active"); nextImg = currentImg.next();` should be placed in function
2. `removeClass(".active")` => `removeClass("active")`.  `addClass(".active") => addClass("active")`
3. next() is a problem.

Except z-index, you can try another attribute -- opacity.